# Instrumentation tests don't ask for user permissions in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, firebase-test-lab

When I run [instrumentation tests in Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/instrumentation-test), the system dialogs asking the user to grant permissions don't come up, as if they were approved without the need for user action. For example when asking to approve screen recording:

```
  val mediaProjMgr = activity.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager
  startForResult.launch(mediaProjMgr.createScreenCaptureIntent())
```

When I run the same test locally the pop up asking to start the recording does show as expected.

How does this work with Test Lab? Do they disable the need for user permissions somehow? What's the mechanism behind it?

Answer (score 2):

By default, all permissions are granted on the Firebase Test lab. To simulate the same environment inside your tests, use [GrantPermissionRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule) in test classes that require permissions.

Comment: Right, FTL installs the app with the -g flag, which automatically grants all manifest permissions to the app. Afterwards, when the instrumentation test is launched, Android won't ask again to grant permissions.

Comment: What permission do I need in order to skip the "Grant permission dialog" in my test when dealing with the MediaProjectionManager ?